# Como se usa e para que serve o 'super' em classes Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Como se usa e para que serve o `super` em `classes` `Python`?

Comment: Olha este blog, só acho que ele traduziu no google, mas ajuda um pouco: http://livretec.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/super-python/

Comment: problema resolvido.

Comment: @user11802 Acabei de perceber que o artigo que você indicou é a tradução em português do artigo que eu havia incluído na minha resposta! :P Alterei minha resposta para fazer referência a ele - pois embora pareça mesmo tradução via Google, pelo menos está no idioma certo...

Comment: a sintaxe `super(Derivada, self).__init__()` também pode ser utilizada em Python3, certo?

Comment: @beteraba Sim, pode. Os dois parâmetros pertencem à [função `super`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#super) e são opcionais.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

O `super` serve para - em uma relação de herança entre uma classe `Base` e outra `Derivada` - permitir que a classe `Derivada` se refira explicitamente à classe `Base`.

Suponha as seguintes classes:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Construindo a classe Base'

class Derivada(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Construindo a classe Derivada'

x = Derivada()
```

Quando esse código for executado, apenas "Construindo a classe Derivada" será impresso na tela, pois o construtor de `Base` não foi chamado em nenhum momento. Se quisermos que ele o seja, temos duas alternativas:

1. Referir-se ao construtor de `Base` diretamente:

   ```
   class Derivada(Base):
       def __init__(self):
           Base.__init__(self)
   ```
2. Usar `super`, permitindo que o interpretador ache a superclasse correta para você:

   ```
   class Derivada(Base):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()               # Python 3
           super(Derivada, self).__init__() # Python 2
   ```

O `super` não serve somente para o construtor, é claro: qualquer método da classe `Base` pode ser chamado dessa forma pela classe `Derivada`:

```
class Derivada(Base):
    def foo(self, arg): pass
    def bar(self, arg):
        super().foo(arg) # Chama o método foo de Base, não de si própria
```

### Vantagens

À primeira vista, não parece haver muita vantagem de se usar o método 2 (com `super`) em relação ao método 1 (nomeando a classe base explicitamente), exceto talvez pelo código mais simples (em Python 3; no 2, ele fica até mais longo!). Mas conforme [esse post](http://livretec.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/super-python/) (tal como [apontado por user11802 nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22452/como-se-usa-e-para-que-serve-o-super-em-classes-python/22461#comment40761_22452)), há situações em que o uso do `super` de fato faz bastante diferença. Considere por exemplo uma subclasse de `dict` que registre num arquivo de log toda vez que um item for alterado:

```
class LoggingDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        logging.info('Setting %r to %r' % (key, value))
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

Suponha que quiséssemos modificar essa classe para herdar de `MeuDict` em vez de `dict`. Nesse caso, bastaria fazer a mudança na definição da classe:

```
class LoggingDict(MeuDict):
```

e todo o resto permaneceria igual. Se o acesso aos métodos base fossem explícitos, teríamos que modificar toda parte que se refere a `dict` para trocar para `MeuDict`. Em outras palavras, o uso do `super` **desacoplou** a classe base e a derivada em certa medida, melhorando a manutenabilidade do código.

O artigo linkado tem outros exemplos para situações mais complexas, alguns envolvendo herança múltipla (situação em que a utilidade do `super` se torna mais evidente).

- Obs.: [Link para o artigo original](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) (em inglês), do qual o post mencionado foi traduzido.

Comment: É como se fosse o `parent` no PHP