# Python Ordem de resolução de métodos (MRO)

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos

Digamos que eu tenha algo parecido com isso:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Base(object):

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        pass

    def grok(self):
        pass


class A(Base):

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        print('A')
        super().foo()

    def grok(self):
        print('a')


class B(Base):

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        print('B')
        super().foo()

    def grok(self):
        print('b')


class C(A, B):

    pass
```

Quando eu chamo o método `grok` fazendo `C().grok()` o mesmo me retorna `'a'`, o que acho correto já que os métodos de `A` tem precedência sobre os de `B`, mas por quê quando eu chamo o métodos de classe `C.foo()` me retorna `'A'` e `'B'`? Não deveria só retornar `'A'`, já que na resolução de métodos no Python ele procura o métodos na classe, se não encontrar procura na sua classe base? Por quê mesmo após encontrar o método na classe `A` ele continua a procurar? Tem algo a ver com o método ser de classe, se sim por quê?

Comment: Testei seu código aqui e só retornou A.

Comment: O que pretendeu fazer com `super().foo()` no próprio método `foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, não tem relação com o método ser de classe, mas sim com a chamada `super().foo()` dentro do método.

Você pode observar a ordem de resolução de nomes, no Python 3.3+, utilizando a função `mro` da classe desejada. Neste caso, na classe `C` ficaria:

```
print(C.mro())
```

O resultado é:

```
[
    <class '__main__.C'>, 
    <class '__main__.A'>, 
    <class '__main__.B'>, 
    <class '__main__.Base'>, 
    <class 'object'>
]
```

Podemos desenhar, então, a árvore de resolução de nomes com base no resultado acima:

```
   ,-------------.  
   |Classe object|  
   `-------------'  
         ^
         |
    ,-----------.  
    |Classe Base|  
    `-----------'  
         ^
         |
     ,--------.  
     |Classe B|  
     `--------'  
         ^
         |
     ,--------.  
     |Classe A|  
     `--------'  
         ^
         |
     ,--------.  
     |Classe C|  
     `--------'
```

Que pode ser resumido como:

1. Ao invocar o método `C.foo`, buscar-se-á primeiro na classe `C`;
2. Caso não encontre, buscar-se-á na classe `A`;
3. Se ainda não encontrar, buscar-se-á na classe `B`;
4. Após, na classe `Base`;
5. E, finalmente, em `object`;
6. Se mesmo assim não encontrar, uma exceção será disparada;

Portanto, quando é invocado `C.foo`, a primeira definição do método que é encontrada é da classe `A`, exibindo, assim, o caractere `'A'` na tela; porém, neste método também é invocado `super().foo()`. Se você ler a documentação da função [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#super), verá que ela retorna um objeto *proxy* para uma classe acima na resolução de nomes. Desta forma, quando `foo()`, na classe `A`, invoca `super().foo()`, o interpretador irá olhar a resolução de nomes acima, retornando um objeto *proxy* para a classe `B`, exibindo, portanto, o caractere `'B'` como resultado. Por sua vez, a implementação de `foo` em `B` também invoca `super().foo()` e, em acordo com a árvore de resolução de nomes, `super()` retornará um objeto *proxy* para a classe `Base`, que também implementa o método `foo`, sem retorno, exibindo `None` na tela como resultado.

Se a implementação em `Base` também invocasse `super().foo()`, uma exceção seria disparada, visto que `super()` seria um objeto *proxy* para a classe `object` e esta não implementa o método `foo`.

Este comportamento tem relação direta com o Problema do Diamante:

- [Herança múltipla e problema do diamante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/233728/5878)
- [Herança é uma má pratica para todas a linguagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173198/5878)

Outras leituras interessantes:

- [Como se usa e para que serve o 'super' em classes Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22452/5878)
- [Diferença entre Pai.__init(self) e super(Pai, self).__init__()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103570/5878)