# Como informar parâmetros ao inicializador da classe mãe com Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Olá, estou fazendo herança no python e estou me deparando com o seguinte erro:

> *TypeError: `__init__()` takes exactly 2 positional arguments (4 given)*

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,c):
        self.c = c
        super().__init__(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a =10
    b = 5
    c = 8
    teste = B(a,b,c)
```

Na classe `B` eu gostaria de utilizar o construtor da classe `A` e adicionar mais um parâmetro no construtor da classe `B`.

Comment: `B(a,b,c)`, estás a chamar o `__init__` de `B` com três argumentos quando a assinatura da função espera apenas um

Comment: Como eu faria para instanciar a classe B e utilizar os parametros a,b do construtor da classe A e também o novo parametro c da classe B?

Comment: Você está mexendo em algum código legado ou só está estudando?
Se você estiver estudando aconselho a estudar python3, senão boa sorte. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um dos [preceitos da linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878) é:

> Explícito é melhor que implícito.

Então não espere nada *mágico* do Python. Você definiu o método `B.__init__` com dois parâmetros, `self` e `c`, então quando instanciar `B` você deve informar apenas o valor de `c` - já que `self` será definido pela linguagem.

Se você precisa que a classe `B` possua os três parâmetros, `a`, `b` e `c` você precisará defini-los explicitamente.

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        ...
```

Mas como a classe `A` é quem trabalha com os valores de `a` e `b`, você precisará passar explicitamente esses valores à instância de `A`:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.c = c
        super().__init__(a, b)
        #                ^--- Não precisa de self aqui
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/RedHiddenUpgrade)</sup>

Assim, todas as classes serão inicializadas com seus devidos valores. Lembre-se que quando você define o método `__init__` na classe filha você sobrescreverá o método da classe mãe, por isso necessita a chamada explícita do mesmo. Leia sobre [Ordem de Resolução de Métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/304178/5878) para entender como é definida a sequência de chamadas.