# É possível herdar uma classe em python sem escrever todos os atributos na definição?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o seguinte código de exemplo:

```
from Testes import POO
class Fisica(POO.Cliente):
    def __init__(self,sexo,nome,idade):
        super().__init__(nome,idade)
        self.sexo = sexo
```

Reparem que os atributos nome e idade são os atributos pertencentes a classe mãe e por isso eu gostaria de saber se tem como herdar uma classe sem ficar especificando todos esses atributos.

Comment: Você não quer passar os parametros em `super().__init__()` ? Tem outro post aqui que fala disso talvez ajude. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22452/como-se-usa-e-para-que-serve-o-super-em-classes-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim -

O jeito mais fácil de fazer não é perfeito - mas é suficiente para a maioria dos casos  -

Trata-se de fazer uso do mecanismo que a linguagem tem de escrever funções que recebem um número arbitrário de parâmetros com nome - para isso, basta preceder o nome de um parâmetro com dois asteriscos - `**` (em quase todo código Python que você olhar, esse parâmetro vai se chamar `kwargs` - abreviação de "Keyword arguments" - ou encurtado para `kw` - no entanto essa é só uma convenção de nome - o importante são os dois `**`.)

Para encurtar, a sua classe derivada acima poderia ficar assim:

```
from Testes import POO
class Fisica(POO.Cliente):
    def __init__(self,sexo, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sexo = sexo
```

Pronto  -o que isso significa: o parâmetro `sexo` é obrigatório para o método `__init__` desta subclasse, e ela não se importa de receber quaisquer outros parâmetros com nome.

O parâmetro `kwargs` dentro deste método será um dicionário de Python - normalzinho, contendo todos os outros argumentos passados. Você pode inspeciona-lo, altera-lo, etc... (experimente colocar um `print(kwargs)`, por exemplo).

E aí, na chamada para `super()...` o mesmo kwargs é usado no mecanismo reverso: quando colocamos `**` no prefixo de um argumento na chamada de uma função ou método, ele assume que a variável após os `**` é um mapa ( "mapping", um dicionário é um tipo específico de mapa) - e desdobra os conteúdos `chave: valor` desse mapa como parâmetros e argumentos para a função chamada.

Nesse caso, se a classe Fisica fosse chamada com `Fisica(sexo='F', nome='Simone', idade=35)`, kwargs seria um dicionário contendo `{'nome': 'Simone', 'idade': 35}`, e `super().__init__(**kwargs)` seria equivalente a  `super().__init__(nome='Simone', idade=35)`

É importante notar que essa sintaxe com dois "**" exige que os argumentos sejam passados com nome - só assim o Python pode criar um dicionário com chaves de par e valor: ou seja, idealmente a chamada tem que ser `Fisica(sexo='F', nome='Simone', idade=35)`. se for desejado trabalhar com parâmetros posicionais. i.e. `Fisica('F', "Simone', 35)`, deve se usar apenas um "*", e o parâmetro recebido com os demais argumentos na ordem em que foram passados é uma tupla, não um dicionário. Justamente por que a assinatura com todos os parâmetros possíveis/desejados não fica explícita na subclasse, é mais recomendado se trabalhar com os argumentos com nome, assim, ninguém precisa "adivinhar" a ordem de envio, e as chamadas podem ser em ordem arbitrária.

Note que esse mecanismo é bastante flexível - se você preferir, pode simplesmente colocar `**kwargs` e nenhum parâmetro a mais na definição do método, e extrair os dados usados por cada subclasse do próprio dicionário, com o método `.pop()`, por exemplo (que recuperar um valor do dicionário e remove o par chave/valor correspondente):

```
class Fisica(POO.Cliente):
    def __init__(self,sexo, **kwargs):
        self.sexo = kwargs.pop('sexo', '-')
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

(O segundo parâmetro para o 'pop' é o valor padrão - no caso, se a pessoa não passasse "sexo" como argumento, a string '-' seria usada).

Por que eu falei que isso não é perfeito? 
Só por que assim alguém que inspecione o método `__init__` da subclasse não tem como ver os nomes e especificações dos parâmetros na superclasse - só apareceriam "sexo" e "kwargs". Então uma IDE que dependa disso para te ajudar com o auto-complete, por exemplo, vai se perder.

Uma boa recomendação nesses casos é documentar os parâmetros extras, que vocẽ sabe serem necessários na doc-string da classe.

Os mecanismos de introspecção de Python permtiriam a criação de um decorator pra classe, por exemplo, que poderia mudar a assinatura dos métodos com kwargs dentro de uma classe para refletir os parâmetros da super-classe - mas isso seria algo bem avançado, e complexo. É até possível que exista algum módulo externo que já faça isso.

Comment: Cara deu certo, mas por algum motivo funcionou apenas com uma *, no caso *kwargs, mas enfim, muito obrigado!

Comment: Um único "*" tem um sentido diferente - é para argumetnos posicionais, enviados sem nome - o objeto resultante, dentro do método, é uma tupla, não um dicionário - você tem acesso aos valores de forma sequencial, mas sem os nomes.
Fora isso, funciona também - se quem chamar o método  passar os argumentos na sequência esperada. (e normalmente é chamado de `args`, não de `kwargs`)

Comment: Acrescentei um parágrafo para falar dos argumentos posicionais.